# Regex will not sub characters '\\'

Tags: python, regex

I want to remove the characters \\ from my string. I have tried regextester and it matches, https://regex101.com/r/euGZsQ/1

```
 s = '''That\\'s not true. There are a range of causes. There are a        range of issues that we have to address. First of all, we have to identify, share and accept that there is a problem and that we\\''''

 pattern = re.compile(r'\\{2,}')
 re.sub(pattern, '', s)
```

I would expect the sub method to replace my \\ with nothing to clean up my string.

Comment: if only wants to remove '\\' why don't you replace it? s.replace("\\\\", "")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your *string itself* is not marked as a raw string. Therefore, the first `\` actually escapes the second.

Observe:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'\\{2,}')
s = r'''That\\'s not true. There are a range of causes. There are a        range of issues that we have to address. First of all, we have to identify, share and accept that there is a problem and that we\\'''
re.sub(pattern, '', s)
```

Output:

```
"That's not true. There are a range of causes. There are a        range of issues that we have to address. First of all, we have to identify, share and accept that there is a problem and that we"
```

Comment: Great it works, will accept when available. However, my actual use case is a string converted from a list with `s = r' '.join(s)`. Converting to a raw string does not solve this problem.

Comment: @franticoreo How do you know that your string in fact has two backslashes? Note that each backslash will be printed twice. Try removing `{2,}` from the regex or just using `.replace('\\', '')`.

Comment: @franticoreo Note also that `r''.join(...)` is the same as `''.join(...)`. "raw string" only has meaning as a *literal*.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
import re
s = '''That\\'s not true. There are a range of causes. There are a        range of issues that we have to address. First of all, we have to identify, share and accept that there is a problem and that we\\' '''
d = re.sub(r'\\', '', s)
print(d)
```

Output :

```
That's not true. There are a range of causes. There are a        range of issues that we have to address. First of all
, we have to identify, share and accept that there is a problem and that we'
```

Comment: Note that this would match a single backslash too.